# How can I convert this object of objects into an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, type-conversion

How can I convert this object:

```
var json = {
    "user3" : {
        "id" : 1
    },
    "user1" : {
        "id" : 3
    },
    "user2" : {
        "id" : 6
    }
}
```

to this array:

```
var json = [{
        "name": "user1",
        "id": 3
    }, {
        "name": "user2",
        "id": 6
    }, {
        "name": "user3",
        "id": 1
    }];
```

Can someone tell me? Or how can I sort an object like the first example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
const src = {
    "user3" : {
        "id" : 1
    },
    "user1" : {
        "id" : 3
    },
    "user2" : {
        "id" : 6
    }
}

const out = Object.keys(src).map((key) => ({name: key, id: src[key].id}))
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, map is simpler by definition

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to iterate over the object items and create an array out of the single items.

```
Object.keys(json).reduce((items, username) => {
const user = json[username];
   return items.concat({
      name: username,
      id: user.id
   });
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.entries` to convert the object into an array. Use `map` to loop thru the array and use `Object.assign` to construct the new object.

```js
var json = {
  "user3": {
    "id": 1
  },
  "user1": {
    "id": 3
  },
  "user2": {
    "id": 6
  }
}

var result = Object.entries(json).map(([k, o]) =>Object.assign(o, {name: k}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach, using a [for-in loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

```
const json = {
    "user3": {
        "id": 1
    },
    "user1": {
        "id": 3
    },
    "user2": {
        "id": 6
    }
}

const result = [];

for (const prop in json) {
    result.push({ "name": prop, "id": json[prop].id });
}

console.log(result);
```

Will provide:

```
[ { name: 'user3', id: 1 },
  { name: 'user1', id: 3 },
  { name: 'user2', id: 6 } ]
```